# Devise scoped view when overriding confirmations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise 2.0.0 and Rails 3.2.3 on OSX.

Is it possible to override both a Devise controller and a Devise view at the same time?

I was successfully overriding the confirmations/new view with my own scoped view, located in `views/users/confirmations/new.html.erb`. The scoped view was working fine.

Then I found it necessary to override the `Devise::ConfirmationsController` with my own controller, `AppConfirmationsController`, in order to customize the after_confirmation_path_for method to return my own custom path.

```
class AppConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  protected
    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
      confirmed_app_custom_path
    end
end
```

I altered the route so that my custom controller would be used

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:confirmations => 'app_confirmations'}
```

The new controller is working fine, but my scoped view is no longer being recognized. Instead of rendering my scoped view, the devise default view is being rendered. If I stop using my custom controller, my scoped view starts working again.

Am I missing some configuration setting that affects scoped views when using a customer controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this will work since I wasn't using scoped views, but I ran into a similar problem when overriding the default devise registration view and controller.

For me I had to make sure the parent directory of my view had the same name as the new devise controller, and everything worked fine.

i.e. `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "app_registrations" }`
and then my custom controller at `views/app_registrations/new.html.erb`

Does moving your view to `views/users/app_confirmations/new.html.erb` help?

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I had tried lots of combinations of view locations, but not that one. The directory for a Devise view must be therefore be `views/<model>/<controller>/<view>`. I did not realize that, but it makes sense now that I think about it